# How to remove Italics in PDF (latex) output of Bookdown ouput (Tufte Style)?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown, tufte

I'm trying to get Bookdown, Tufte style, to output to PDF with similiar aesthetics to the "Envisioned" style. I've been able to change fonts by using "includes" in the YAML data, and linking to a .tex file.

Now I would like to remove the Italics from the PDF output. (The equivalent to toggling the "italics" feature off in the HTML output).

Any help on this would really be welcome.

This is .tex file:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white}
\setmainfont{Roboto Condensed}
\setsansfont{Roboto Condensed}
```

The outcome I'm trying to produce is equivalent to the following line in the HTML YAML data:

```
tufte_features: ["fonts", "background"]
```

where Italics is missing and therefore switched off.

I'm a newbie who really likes the Tufte style sidenotes, so please forgive my silly question if there is something simple I have missed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The bookdown tufte package relies on the latex `\maketitle`, which you can alter using a latex package `titling`. So, for example, you can remove *italics* and replace with a **bold** font and flush left the title by including a bit of latex code in the yaml:

```
---
title: "Tufte Handout"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\bfseries} 
  - \posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}}
output:
  bookdown::tufte_handout2
---
```

You can also change the section formatting using the yaml. For example,

```
  - \titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
  - \titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
```

`Large` and `large` changes the font sizes, `bfseries` sets the font to bold face, and `sffamily` changes the font to san serif.