# set different fonts for the body and margin notes for tufte bookdown pdf

Tags: r, latex, bookdown, tufte

I'd like to set different fonts for the body and margin notes of a `bookdown::pdf_book` with `base_format: tufte::tufte_book`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59418039/841405) shows how to change the overall styling by adding to `header-includes:` in the YAML.

Is there a similar latex approach for setting different fonts/sizes to control the main vs margin note text?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] including the intermediate `.tex` file?

Comment: Thanks, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I didn't think about the intermediate `.tex` file. I posted it here: https://gist.github.com/ericpgreen/6e0a5b5beedf4540930c4636cd0059ad

Comment: Margin content includes references, captions, footnotes, and anything I put in Rmarkdown `{marginfigure}` code chunks.

Comment: off-topic: I would use `\marginnote{...}` for marginnotes and not marginfigures

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn’t aware that was an option in bookdown/tufte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the fonts like this:

```
\setmainfont{Arial} % font of the main body
\setsidenotefont{\fontspec{Zapfino}} 
\setcaptionfont{\fontspec{Zapfino}} 
\setmarginnotefont{\fontspec{Zapfino}} 
\setcitationfont{\fontspec{Zapfino}}
```

[image]